# Using the sharepoint stsadm import command fails when list exists

Tags: list, sharepoint-2007, import, stsadm

When using the stsadm -o import command in sharepoint I am getting an error relating to a list already existing, the import then seems to fail. Should it not handle this scenario of a list already existing on the destination server?

I then used the UI to delete the existing list and ran the import again. It then seemed to fail at the same point saying the list exists. In the UI the list appears but when I click it, it reports that the list does not exist - almost as if it's stuck in a half created state, unable to be deleted or created by the import.

Any suggestions greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try the command again using the -overwrite switch.